# How to parse value from nested json into tableview cell with multiple label in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, alamofire

I have tableView with a cell of multiple labels. Having cell-like, set-1 **variableName1, variablevalue1** & set-2 **variableName2, variablevalue2**. Here all the data will get from JSON responses including the title label.

I have stored all values to model and showing some data in tableView. but I could not able to show the multiple label values alone.

Here is my JSON structure for multiple labels:

```
    "_embedded": {
                "variable": [
                    {
                        "_links": {
                            "self": {
                                "href": ""
                            }
                        },
                        "_embedded": null,
                        "name": "startedBy",
                        "value": "Preethi",
                        "type": "String",
                        "valueInfo": {}
                    },
                    {
                        "_links": {
                            "self": {
                                "href": ""
                            }
                        },
                        "_embedded": null,
                        "name": "LoanAmount",
                        "value": "1500000",
                        "type": "String",
                        "valueInfo": {}
                    }
                ]
            },
```

Here I am trying to show the value from the **variable** array -> name & value.

Tried so far like this:

```
       for val in (t._embedded?.variable)!{
        
        print("val name", val.name ?? "")
        print("val name", val.value ?? "")
        

        
        if val.name == val.name {

            cell.variableName1.text = val.name
            cell.variablevalue1.text = val.value
        }


        if val.value == val.value {

            cell.variableName2.text = val.name
            cell.variablevalue2.text = val.value

        }
    }
```

here the image of the tableView cell:

[image]

Any help much appreciated pls...

Comment: you can use tableview in collection-view. tableview section in variable.count and tableview number of rows static return 1 after collection reload. collection view number of rows -> variable.count after collection view cell for indexpath in two labels in one for name and  one for value...i think my logic working. now i have to create one for demo end send to you.

Comment: expire your bounty +50 please accept my answer otherwise you lost +50 bounty point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TableView in CollectionView

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

//MARK: - Variable Declaration
let arryOfData = [["name": "startedBy","value": "Preethi"],["name": "LoanAmount","value": "1500000"]]
//MARK: - IBOutlet
@IBOutlet weak var tblView:UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

// MARK: - UITableview DELEGATE AND DATASOURCE
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1 // If you more data than use dynamic count set
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tblView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ListCell
    cell.clcView.reloadData()
    return cell
}

// MARK: - UICOLLECTION DELEGATE AND DATASOURCE
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.arryOfData.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath)
    let lblName = cell.viewWithTag(101) as! UILabel
    let lblValue = cell.viewWithTag(102) as! UILabel
    lblName.layer.borderWidth = 1
    lblName.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    lblValue.layer.borderWidth = 1
    lblValue.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    let dict = self.arryOfData[indexPath.row]
    lblName.text = dict["name"] ?? ""
    lblValue.text = dict["value"] ?? ""
    return cell
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let spacing:CGFloat = 10
    let numberOfItemsPerRow:CGFloat = 2
    let spacingBetweenCells:CGFloat = 10
    let totalSpacing = (2 * spacing) + ((numberOfItemsPerRow) * spacingBetweenCells)
    let productWidth = (collectionView.bounds.width - totalSpacing)/numberOfItemsPerRow
    return CGSize(width: productWidth, height: 110)
    
   }
}

class ListCell: UITableViewCell {
    //MARK: - Variable Declaration
    
    //MARK: - IBOutlet
    @IBOutlet weak var clcView:UICollectionView!
    
    //MARK: - LifeCycle
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
    //MARK: - IBAction

 }
```

[image: your output]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Thought doing this already. do we have other solutions?

Comment: How does this solution not solve your problem? If you are already doing this, what do you want? Perhaps provide more of the actual code you're using along with more details about how you've structured your app.

Comment: @PvUIDev second solution is you can create custom arraryofdictionary and than show only table view.

Answer (score 0):

```
for val in (t._embedded?.variable)!{
    

    if val.name == val.name {

        cell.variableName1.text = val.name
        cell.variablevalue1.text = val.value
    }


    if val.value == val.value {

        cell.variableName2.text = val.name
        cell.variablevalue2.text = val.value

    }
}
```

If you compare **val.name == val.name** it always returns true so you need to modify like this **val.name == "startedBy"** and for value **val.value == "1500000"** to display the first item and second item of the json.

Anyway where do you call the for loop?
I think you want to display each item of the json in a unique cell so you need to parse the json into a dictionary and use it in the "cellForItemAt" function of CollectionViewDataSource

Answer (score 0):

There is little information on what you really want but maybe this can help.

### Case 1

I feel like your json may not be properly defined. If it is, then it seems to say that you will only have one set of two variables, then you wouldn't need a `UITableView` because there would be only one cell, that way you could accomplish that by just adding one `UIView` to your current view.

If you:

- will always have only two variables in the json
- want to show their content in one cell
- are using UITableView

On `cellForRow(at:)` you can

```swift
func cellForRow(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let cell = self.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath) else { return UITableViewCell() }

    for val in (t._embedded?.variable)! {
        
        // The if you had here is always true
        cell.variableName1.text = val.name
        cell.variablevalue1.text = val.value

        cell.variableName2.text = val.name
        cell.variablevalue2.text = val.value
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

### Case 2

If your json is properly defined but you will have more than two variables and you want to show two per row then I would suggest you used `UICollectionViewCell` and have your cells take half the screen in size each and in each one you show the value of the proper index. Something like this:

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath),
          cellInfo = t._embedded?.variable[indexPath.item] else { return UICollectionViewCell() }

    cell.variableName.text = cellInfo.name
    cell.variableValue.text = cellInfo.value

    return cell
}

// MARK: Size of the cells
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let midWidthPoint = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width / 2

    return CGSize(width: midWidthPoint, height: 100)
}
```

### Case 3

If none of these is still the case you want solved please let us know so that we can better help you.